# Searching a value in a nested Map in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, nested, maps

I am trying to look through a nested map for a specific value using java8.
Example:
The map is a

```
Map<Integer, Map<String,String>> classStudentGrp;
```

and some of the records are like

```
StudentId1:
StudentName:Andy
StudentAge:12
StudentAddress:xxxx

StudentId1:
StudentName:Anna
StudentAge:11
StudentAddress:yyyy
```

and so on.

I am looking at something like

```
classStudentGrp.forEach((sid,stu)->stu.forEach((sAttr,val)->val.equals("Andy")));
```

and I want to either return a boolean (true) or set a variable if 'Andy' is found. I know the traditional approach using entry keys and values, but trying to do this in lambda.

Comment: I would recommend using a `Student` object instead of a nested map.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you create a `Student` class instead of just having a `String` in the format:

```
StudentId1:
StudentName:Andy
StudentAge:12
StudentAddress:xxxx
```

Java is an Object Oriented language, and it is best to use it as such. You can create a class like:

```
class Student {
   private String name;
   private String id;
   private int age;
   private String address;  
   //Getters and setters
   //Appropriate constructors
}
```

Then you could do:

```
boolean value = classStudentGrp.values().stream()
                                        .anyMatch(e -> e.getName().equals("Andy"));
```

Which will take a `Stream` of the values of `classStudentGrp` (The `Map<String, Student`), take the values of that `Map` (A `Stream<Students>`) and then use `anyMatch` to determine if any of the `Students` have the name "Andy"

Answer (score 1):

You can test it with this:

```
boolean contains = classStudentGrp.values().stream()
        .anyMatch(m -> m.containsValue("Andy"));
```

But you should use a Student object like this:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    // ...
}
```

With a `List<Student>` you can use just this:

```
boolean contains = classStudentGrp.stream().anyMatch(s -> "Andy".equals(s.getName()))
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to below example

```java
List<String> result = lines.stream()                // convert list to stream
  .filter(line -> "mkyong".equals(line))            // we dont like mkyong
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

coming from https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/